# Abort save in m2m_changed phase with Django

Tags: python, django, m2m

I need to save a django many-to-many field to a third-party server when saving a model. However, the third party server might be unavailable, in which case I need to abort the whole save operation.

Is it possible to abort saving a model from the m2m_changed phase?

Comment: Yeah. If unavailable just call `instance.delete()`  or in the `save` method check availability of the service and then save.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and this is officially supported by the [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/) framework. It basically allows you to save (outside the database) what would be the database changes until you actually tell him to commit that change.

By waiting for a third party, you can commit or discard the transaction. This can even be made on a request/response basis, by the transaction's middleware.

Be careful though about the version you are using of Django, as transactions suffered some changes on 1.6.